# Freemarker WebappTemplateLoader in FreemarkerConfigurer

Tags: spring-mvc, freemarker

Anyone has an example on how to use Freemarker WebappTemplateLoader in FreemarkerConfigurer?

I am using Freemarker with Spring MVC and extending the FreeMarkerConfigurer to add various template loaders and I would also like to add a web app loader to load templates in web app context. But I do not know how to get the servletcontext parameter for its constructor.

```
public class DesktopFreeMarkerConfigurer extends FreeMarkerConfigurer{  

@Override
protected void postProcessConfiguration(Configuration config){
    [...]
        /* Get templates from the webapp/servlet context */
    WebappTemplateLoader watl = new WebappTemplateLoader(<servletContext>, "default/ftl/");
    [...]
    }
}
```

I would like to add webapp/default/ftl to template loading path, but as it may be dynamic/configurable, I cannot hardcode it in the xml files.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you
Carmen

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are defining DesktopFreeMarkerConfigurer as a spring bean.
In that case, it should be simple to get the servlet context. 
Just define this in the DesktopFreeMarkerConfigurer class :

```
@Autowired private ServletContext context;
```

Or if you choose, you can also make it implements ServletContextAware :

```
public class DesktopFreeMarkerConfigurer extends FreeMarkerConfigurer implements ServletContextAware {
    private ServletContext servletContext;

    public void setServletContext(ServletContext servletContext) {
        this.servletContext = servletContext;
    }

    @Override
    protected void postProcessConfiguration(Configuration config){
        WebappTemplateLoader watl = new WebappTemplateLoader(this.servletContext, "default/ftl/");
        ...
    }

    ...
}
```