# freemarker div-close.ftl not found upgrading to JBoss 7

Tags: templates, struts2, freemarker

I need to migrate a ".war" application that is running perfectly well on Jboss 4.2.3 to a newer version of JBoss.
I've chosen "jboss-as-7.1.1.Final".

After some minor adjustments, I could get the application loaded, but first access to login page returned a freemarker configuration error regarding the absence of file "div-close.ftl".
I've found a folder named "freemarker" with inner folders with templates which are: "ajax", "simple", "xhtml" and "whtml".
The missing "div-close.ftl" in fact is not present on "xhtml" folder (which is the default ui template), but I think this work on older JBoss probably because of a fallback to "simple" when a given file is not present on a specific and more elaborated ui template folder (please correct me if I'm wrong).

The only dependency change I needed to make was to upgrade struts dependencies from version 2.2.1 to 2.3.1.
Following, the freemarker dependency was upgraded from version 2.3.16 to 2.3.18.

I configured the old version 2.3.16 in order to solve the problem, but no luck, so I tried to copy the missing file from "simple" folder to "xhtml" and this issue stopped, but I've got the same kind of error navigating through the application, but complaining of template files not found now on "whtml" folder.

Things seems to be a little messed up and I don't know where to start digging. Is this a freemarker issue? Is it a struts issue?

Does anyone had this same issue, or can help me out?

Answer (score 0):

In the `freemareker.template.Configuration` object there's a `templateLoader` JavaBean property (`getTemplateLoader`/`setTemplateLoader` method pair). The `TemplateLoader` object specifies how the templates are found and loaded. You certainly have a `MultiTemplateLoader` there, which calls a list of other `TemplateLoader`-s to implement the fall back behavior. Some of those delegate `TemplateLoader`-s is broken, apparently. The usual mistake is getting the file path ("real path") of a template directory, then creating a `FileTemplateLoader` from it. The problem with that is that nor `ServletContext` resources nor `ClassLoader` resources are guaranteed to exist as real files. As far as I have seen, on JBoss AS 7 they really aren't. Even if the `war` was extracted, JBoss won't give you the "real" file path, so you have to do things properly. That is, just use `ClassTemplateLoader` or `WebappTemplateLoader` instead of `FileTemplateLoader`.

Also, if you are upgrading FreeMarker anyway, there's no reason to stop before 2.3.21 (the latest 2.3.x when I write this). Among others, it puts into the error message what `TemplateLoader`-s it has used to find the template. That would be helpful now.

Comment: Thank's a lot for you detailed reply. My first try to replace the "TemplateLoader" using instructions found on site "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14956396/freemarker-webapptemplateloader-in-freemarkerconfigurer", haven't worked. For some reason, it seems that spring is not loading my custom bean. I'll make another attempts by next days and post here the result as soon as possible. Thank's again and best regards.